# How to convert a PHP array into a string that looks just like the array as represented in the source code?

Tags: php, arrays

Let's say I have an array like this:

`array('one' => 'one')`

How can I get the string:

`"array('one' => 'one')"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `var_export`.

```
$array = array('one' => 'one');
$string = var_export($array, true);
```

For more information on the function, see the PHP documentation. https://www.php.net/var_export